# Kotlin - only one textView is visible before tapping button

Tags: android, kotlin

Any idea why the top textView (textView2) is visible before tapping the top button (button2)? Bottom textView (textView1) doesn't do that and I'm a little confused, below is my code.

The program basically rolls dice when tapping one of the buttons and display the rolled value on top, it's part of the ANDROID BASICS IN KOTLIN course by Google. The dice on top has two sides and the bottom one has 6.

I'm new to Android/Kotlin programming and just trying to learn, I searched this forum and there are ways to hide it but I don't recall doing such a thing for the bottom textView.

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated!

[App simulation before clicking the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c04kM.png)
[activity_main.xml view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aglv5.png)

```
 package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

/**
 * This activity allows the user to roll a dice and view the result
 * on the screen.
 */
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //change button2 name to Roll
        val resultButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button2)
        resultButton.text = "Roll"

        val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        rollButton.setOnClickListener { rollDice() }

        val rollButton2: Button = findViewById(R.id.button2)
        rollButton2.setOnClickListener{ rollDice2() }
    }

    /**
     * Roll the dice and update the screen with the result.
     */
    private fun rollDice() {
        // Create new Dice object with 6 sides and roll it
        val dice = Dice(6)
        val diceRoll = dice.roll()

        // Update the screen with the dice roll
        val resultTextView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)

        // convert diceRoll to a string so resultTextView can be updated
        resultTextView.text = diceRoll.toString()
    }

    private fun rollDice2() {
        // Create new Dice object with 2 sides and roll it
        val dice = Dice(2)
        val diceRoll = dice.roll()

        // Update the screen with the dice roll
        val resultTextView2: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView2)

        // convert diceRoll to a string so resultTextView can be updated
        resultTextView2.text = diceRoll.toString()
    }
}

class Dice(val numSides: Int) {

    fun roll(): Int {
        return (1..numSides).random()
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the xml code of your layout? When I click on acticity_main.xml I only see the design but not the code.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom `textView` text would be using `xmlns:tools` which basically shows the value in the preview and not in the actual build. Make sure it starts with `android` prefix rather than `tools`:

```
android:text="1"
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I follow, I don't see "android:text" anywhere

Comment: @Moya.A your code doesn't set the text on any `TextView`s until you press one of the buttons - so if there's already text displayed before you do anything, it must already be set on that `TextView` by default. If you look in your `activity_main.xml` layout file, the top one probably has text set on it with ``android:text``. The bottom one might be using `tools:text`, which is the same thing but only visible in the layout editor, not applied when the app is actually running, so that one would look empty ("invisible") when you run it